# A-frame timeline based animation editor

Tags: javascript, animation, 3d, aframe

I am a newby researching the best javascript 3D solution to support development of web based 3D (incl VR) technical training. I imagine a combination of scripted animation with audio (voice over) synced to the animation and the ability for the user to interact with the 3D environment (clicking objects to display information etc).

Is there an implementation of a visual timeline editor in A-frame for scripting animation events (timing for object to display, transitions, audio etc)?

Answer (score 2):

There is not a visual timeline editor for A-Frame, no. You may be able to do this sort of thing with three.js-based [frame.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/frame.js/) and export to JSON, which A-Frame can import. But the safest bet is probably to use DCC tools (Blender, Maya, 3DS Max) to script your animation and export to a model you can load in A-Frame. Combining that sort of animation with user interaction in WebVR is very much an open field with few established practices.